# How to implement 'quick return' with scrollview in android

Tags: android, scrollview

I want to implement 'Quick return header' with ScrollView. My header is not toolbar, it's FrameLayout..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you need to use the `Nested Scrolling` (added in API 21). This feature allows a child (the scrolling one) to communicate with its parent (typically the `CoordinatorLayout`). However, in order to have the Nested Scrolling, you need that:

1. Parent view must implement [NestedScrollingParent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingParent.html) interface
2. Child view must implement [NestedScrollingChild](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild.html) interface

`CoordinatorLayout` implements `NestedScrollingParent`, but unfortunally, `ScrollView` does not implement `NestedScrollingChild` interface.

So, **YOU CAN'T HAVE A NESTED SCROLLING USING SCROLLVIEW** (before API 21: look the EDIT section on the bottom). However you can use a `NestedScrollView` that basically is a `ScrollView` that implements the `NestedScrollingChild` interface.

After that, you need to create a custom `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` and override the method `onStartNestedScroll`, `onNestedPreScroll` and `onNestedScroll`. Below you can see the code that match your need (I took it from [this example](https://github.com/devunwired/coordinated-effort/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/coordinatedeffort/behaviors/QuickHideBehavior.java) with some changes).

Supposing that you view is a `FramLayout` you can do something like this in your layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="84dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        app:layout_behavior=".QuickHideBehavior">
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As you can see a custom behavior is attached to the `FrameLayout`. Then you need to modify the above [QuickHideBehavior](https://github.com/devunwired/coordinated-effort/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/coordinatedeffort/behaviors/QuickHideBehavior.java) example in this way:

```
public class QuickHideBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View> {

    private static final int DIRECTION_UP = 1;
    private static final int DIRECTION_DOWN = -1;

    /* Tracking direction of user motion */
    private int mScrollingDirection;
    /* Tracking last threshold crossed */
    private int mScrollTrigger;

    /* Accumulated scroll distance */
    private int mScrollDistance;
    /* Distance threshold to trigger animation */
    private int mScrollThreshold;


    private ObjectAnimator mAnimator;

    //Required to instantiate as a default behavior
    public QuickHideBehavior() {
    }

    //Required to attach behavior via XML
    public QuickHideBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a = context.getTheme()
                .obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] {R.attr.actionBarSize});
        //Use half the standard action bar height
        mScrollThreshold = a.getDimensionPixelSize(0, 0) / 2;
        a.recycle();
    }

    //Called before a nested scroll event. Return true to declare interest
    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
                                       View child, View directTargetChild, View target,
                                       int nestedScrollAxes) {
        //We have to declare interest in the scroll to receive further events
        return (nestedScrollAxes & ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL) != 0;
    }

    //Called before the scrolling child consumes the event
    // We can steal all/part of the event by filling in the consumed array
    @Override
    public void onNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
                                  View child, View target,
                                  int dx, int dy,
                                  int[] consumed) {
        //Determine direction changes here
        if (dy > 0 && mScrollingDirection != DIRECTION_UP) {
            mScrollingDirection = DIRECTION_UP;
            mScrollDistance = 0;
        } else if (dy < 0 && mScrollingDirection != DIRECTION_DOWN) {
            mScrollingDirection = DIRECTION_DOWN;
            mScrollDistance = 0;
        }
    }

    //Called after the scrolling child consumes the event, with amount consumed
    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
                               View child, View target,
                               int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed,
                               int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
        //Consumed distance is the actual distance traveled by the scrolling view
        mScrollDistance += dyConsumed;
        if (mScrollDistance > mScrollThreshold
                && mScrollTrigger != DIRECTION_UP) {
            //Hide the target view
            mScrollTrigger = DIRECTION_UP;
            restartAnimator(child, getTargetHideValue(coordinatorLayout, child));
        } else if (mScrollDistance < -mScrollThreshold
                && mScrollTrigger != DIRECTION_DOWN) {
            //Return the target view
            mScrollTrigger = DIRECTION_DOWN;
            restartAnimator(child, 0f);
        }
    }

    //Called after the scrolling child handles the fling
    @Override
    public boolean onNestedFling(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
                                 View child, View target,
                                 float velocityX, float velocityY,
                                 boolean consumed) {
        //We only care when the target view is already handling the fling
        if (consumed) {
            if (velocityY > 0 && mScrollTrigger != DIRECTION_UP) {
                mScrollTrigger = DIRECTION_UP;
                restartAnimator(child, getTargetHideValue(coordinatorLayout, child));
            } else if (velocityY < 0 && mScrollTrigger != DIRECTION_DOWN) {
                mScrollTrigger = DIRECTION_DOWN;
                restartAnimator(child, 0f);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /* Helper Methods */

    //Helper to trigger hide/show animation
    private void restartAnimator(View target, float value) {
        if (mAnimator != null) {
            mAnimator.cancel();
            mAnimator = null;
        }

        mAnimator = ObjectAnimator
                .ofFloat(target, View.TRANSLATION_Y, value)
                .setDuration(250);

        /*mAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "alpha", 0f, 1f).setDuration(250);*/
        mAnimator.start();
    }

    private float getTargetHideValue(ViewGroup parent, View target) {
        if(target instanceof FrameLayout)
            return -target.getHeight();

        return 0f;
    }
}
```

And you are done.

I recommend you to take a look [here](https://github.com/devunwired/coordinated-effort) for more examples or [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5o2hGMMmIw) both by *Dave Smith*

**EDIT:** Actually, since API 21, `ScrollView` (or `ListView`) supports Nested Scrolling, but you need to enable it:

```
scrollView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```

and you need, of course, to set

`minSdkVersion > 20`

Comment: Many thanks Joseph, could you please explain further how to apply your solution in my layout.

Here is my layout:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include layout="@layout/layout_header_search" />
            /* My content */
    </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>

Comment: I want to apply quick return for layout_header_search that's FrameLayout sir.

Comment: @NaPro I have edited my answer. I have also tested it on my device: it works. Try it.

Comment: Joseph, you mean my application has to set minSdkVersion = 21?

Comment: Hi Joseph, i just tried your solution but not sure why it's not working. I have tried this solution: https://android-arsenal.com/details/3/698 and it's working but not well as what i want, when header is hidden there is still 'white section' with height = header's height :-s

Comment: @NaPro no, you need to set minSdkVersion = 21, only if you use the `ScollView`. I suggest you, instead, to use the `NestedScrollView` as done in my example, so that you don't require 21 as minSdkVersion. I have tested my example, and it works. Which problems are you having?

Comment: Hi Joseph, i set margin_top for NestedScrollView by header height, could you please tell me how to remove white section when header hidden? If i don't set margin_top so header will cover NestedScrollView.

Comment: @NaPro I think that you should focus on what behavior you really need. An idea can be to move up the ScrollView while the `FrameLayout` is going up. But in this case I'm not sure that the user will be happy seeing the `ScrollView` that moves faster that its finger. However, if you like this option, you should consume the event inside the prescroll (managing the  consumed[] array) and don't start scrolling until the `FrameLayout` disappears and the `ScrollView` is pushed up. You can get a hint looking at the source code of `AppBarLayout`.

Comment: Any way, many thanks Joseph!

Comment: You are welcome @NaPro ;)